# Rails 4.2.0 flash causes "We're sorry, but something went wrong"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing first app in Raisl 4 on localhost.
I want to use flash helper, but any time I put fe.:

```
flash[:error] = "Some erorr."
```

In any place on method, I get error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong. (...)
```

On logs I have:

```
Started POST "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-13 17:55:16 +0100
```

Method:

```
def login
    redirect_to start_url if session[:user_id]      
    if params["login"]
        require 'digest/md5'
        password = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params["login"]["password"])
        @user = User.find_by(email: params["login"]["email"], password: password, active: true)
        if @user
           session[:user_id] = @user.id
            redirect_to start_url
         else
            flash[:error] = "Error at sign-in ."
            redirect_to root_url
        end
     end
end
```

Same behavior occurs in other actions as well.
I have default configuration on app and domain testrails.local

I had tried passing by

```
flash.now[:error]
```

and also by redirect

```
redirect_to root_url, flash: {error: "some error" }
```

Without redirect it works

**SOLVED:**

Text in flash has trouble with encoding. I've added some like ś,ą,ć and it was error.

Comment: The server is returning a 5xx. View the logs - there is probably a runtime exception.

Comment: I did checked log/development.log in there is only:
Started POST "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-13 17:55:16 +0100

Comment: @Ayrlard - How  sure are you that it's flash which is causing the error?

Comment: @Aylard Your log file in `log` directory must contain detail information about your problem (error + backtrace). You should find it and provide information about error because without it very hard to investigate reason of your problem.

Comment: I did.  Only line in only file besides .keep is this one that it Started POST . Maybe I didn't enable something   

I am sure becuase if i comment it, it works.